# Promises seem to not be called in correct order?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

I am trying to rewrite a module I wrote that seeds a MongoDB database. It was originally working fine with callbacks, but I want to move to Promises. However, the execution and results don't seem to make any sense.

There are three general functions in a `Seeder` object:

```
// functions will be renamed
Seeder.prototype.connectPromise = function (url, opts) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        try {
            mongoose.connect(url, opts).then(() => {
                const connected = mongoose.connection.readyState == 1
                this.connected = connected
                resolve(connected)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
    })
}
[...]
Seeder.prototype.seedDataPromise = function (data) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if (!this.connected) reject(new Error('Not connected to MongoDB'))
        // Stores all promises to be resolved
        var promises = []
        // Fetch the model via its name string from mongoose
        const Model = mongoose.model(data.model)
        // For each object in the 'documents' field of the main object
        data.documents.forEach((item) => {
            // generates a Promise for a single item insertion.
            promises.push(promise(Model, item))
        })
        // Fulfil each Promise in parallel
        Promise.all(promises).then(resolve(true)).catch((e)=>{
            reject(e)
        })
    })
}
[...]
Seeder.prototype.disconnect = function () {
    mongoose.disconnect()
    this.connected = false
    this.listeners.forEach((l) => {
        if (l.cause == 'onDisconnect') l.effect()
   })
}
```

There is no issue with the main logic of the code. I can get it to seed the data correctly. However, when using Promises, the database is disconnected before anything else is every done, despite the disconnect function being called `.finally()`.

I am running these functions like this:

```
Seeder.addListener('onConnect', function onConnect () { console.log('Connected') })
Seeder.addListener('onDisconnect', function onDisconnect () {console.log('Disconnected')})

Seeder.connectPromise(mongoURI, options).then(
    Seeder.seedDataPromise(data)
    ).catch((error) => {  <-- I am catching the error, why is it saying its unhandled?
        console.error(error)
}).finally(Seeder.disconnect())
```

The output is this:

```
Disconnected
(node:14688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not connected to MongoDB
    at Promise (C:\Users\johnn\Documents\Code\node projects\mongoose-seeder\seed.js:83:37)
```

which frankly doesn't make sense to me, as on the line pointed out in the stack trace I call reject(). And this rejection is handled, because I have a catch statement as shown above. Further, I can't understand why the database never even has a chance to connect, given the finally() block should be called last.

The solution was to return the `Promise.all` call, in addition to other suggestions.

Comment: Your `connectPromise()` function is a promise anti-pattern.  There's no reason to wrap an existing promise in a manually created promise wrapper.  
That is considered a promise anti-pattern.  Just do `return mongoose.connect().then();`.  That will return your promise just fine.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to your question. The format of Stack Overflow is that questions appear in the questions section, and answers in the answers section.

Comment: No. For anyone searching, seeing the answer immediately is more useful.

Comment: No. That is not how Stack Overflow works ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216719/should-i-edit-my-question-or-post-a-new-answer)). I have reverted your change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong argument to `then` and `finally`. First here:

```
Seeder.connectPromise(mongoURI, options).then(
    Seeder.seedDataPromise(data)
)
```

Instead of passing a callback function to `then`, you actually *execute* the function on the spot (so without waiting for the promise to resolve and trigger the `then` callback -- which is not a callback).

You should do:

```
Seeder.connectPromise(mongoURI, options).then(
    () => Seeder.seedDataPromise(data)
)
```

A similar error is made here:

```
finally(Seeder.disconnect())
```

It should be:

```
finally(() => Seeder.disconnect())
```

## Promise Constructor Anti-Pattern

Not related to your question, but you are implementing an antipattern, by creating new promises with `new Promise`, when in fact you already get promises from using the mongodb API.

For instance, you do this here:

```
Seeder.prototype.connectPromise = function (url, opts) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        try {
            mongoose.connect(url, opts).then(() => {
                const connected = mongoose.connection.readyState == 1
                this.connected = connected
                resolve(connected)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
    })
}
```

But the wrapping promise, created with `new` is just a wrapper that adds nothing useful. Just write:

```
Seeder.prototype.connectPromise = function (url, opts) {
    return mongoose.connect(url, opts).then(() => {
        const connected = mongoose.connection.readyState == 1
        this.connected = connected
        return connected;
    });
}
```

The same happens in your next prototype function. I'll leave it to you to apply a similar simplification there, so avoiding the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

---

In the later edit to your question, you included this change, but you did not return a promise in that function. Add `return` here:

```
  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
//^^^^^^
      return true
  }).catch(() => {
      console.log(`Connected:\t${this.connected}`)
  })
```

Comment: I've made some changes, it makes the connection to the DB, the seeding function is called, but disconnect is still called before seedData can finish.

Comment: That is because you must `return Promise.all(...`, otherwise your function is not returning a promise.

Comment: That got it! Thank you! I will be looking over all of my code to make sure I understand it fully and it is as clean as possible